# Spring MVC -- requested resource() not available

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring 3.1 MVC application, and I have a JSP that is not rendering at all in my browser.  Instead, I see a message that says, "The requested resource () is not available."  Can anyone help?  Here is my error message.

```
    HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource () is not available.
```

This is GuestBook.jsp.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="myTag" uri="commentsTag"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Granada High School Class of 1986 Comment Page</title>
<!-- Put a confirmation message here once you
     figure out how to do it with Spring -->
<style type="text/css">
p {
    text-align: justify;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Granada High School Class of 1986 Guest Book</h1>
    <%@ include file="menu.jsp"%><br>
    <b><font color="red"><c:out value='${confirmation}' /></font></b>
    <c:remove var="confirmation" scope="session" />
    <p>This page is a place where you can share memories from high
        school, what you're doing these days, comments about this web site
        (good or bad), etc. The comments will appear at the bottom of the
        page.</p>
    <form:form method="post" action="GuestBook.jsp" modelAttribute="comment">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="message">Message</form:label></td>
                <td><form:textarea path="message" rows="10" cols="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit comment" /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
    <br>
    <myTag:comments />
    <%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is com.controller.CommentController.java.

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.dao.CommentDAO;
import com.model.Comment;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/GuestBook.jsp")
public class CommentController {
    Comment comment;

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(Comment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/GuestBook", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addComment(@ModelAttribute("comment") Comment comment, BindingResult result) {
        CommentDAO commentDAO = new CommentDAO();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
        comment.setDate(date);

        if (commentDAO.writeComment(comment) == true) {
            return "redirect:GuestBook.jsp";
        }

        return "redirect:Oops.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/GuestBook")
    public ModelAndView showComments() {
        return new ModelAndView("comments", "command", new Comment());
    }
}
```

This is web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Granada High School Class of 1986</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ghs1986</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ghs1986</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.configuration.ConfigurationListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is applicationContext.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This is ghs1986-servlet.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC
"-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean name="comment" class="com.model.Comment" />

    <bean name="/GuestBook.jsp" class="com.controller.CommentController">
        <property name="comment" ref="comment" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following :

1) In web.xml, change

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

to

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

2) move the code

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

from applicationContext.xml to ghs1986-servlet.xml

3) In CommentController, change `@RequestMapping("/GuestBook.jsp")` to `@RequestMapping("/GuestBook")`

4) Still in CommentController, change

```
@RequestMapping("/GuestBook")
public ModelAndView showComments() {
...
}
```

to something like

```
@RequestMapping("/showComments")
public ModelAndView showComments() {
...
}
```

Now try again with a url like `http://localhost:<your_port>/GuestBook/showComments`. You should have access to your page. There may have other errors, but we are only dealing with the 404 one here.

5) Optional (but strongly recommended) : read some doc + a good [getting started tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) to learn the basic best practises and how to set things up.